# Is it dangerous to pass a pointer to a subobject that is not constructed yet to a constructor of another subobject during the object construction?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, type-conversion, this

The subobject won't be used before its construction, only the pointer to it will be stored.

Consider the following code:

```
class Base1;

class Base0 
{
public:
    Base0(Base1* obj1) : 
        anotherObj(new AnotherClass(obj1)) // only saves the pointer, doesn't use the object 
    {}

    AnotherClass* anotherObj;
};

class Base1 { /*...*/ };

class Derived : public Base0, public Base1
{
public:
    Derived() :
        Base0(this), // expecting an implicit conversion of Derived* to Base1*
        Base1()
    {}
};
```

Is it possible to upcast this pointer to any of bases before any construction of bases occurs and get a valid pointer? And what about more complicated cases such as virtual inheritance?

Comment: At the time the constructor of `Base0` runs, the constructor of `Base1` has not been yet called, so it should be considered uninitialized.

Comment: Uninitialized, yes. But pointers can point to uninitialized regions of memory as well. It can't be used. But can it be stored before the initialization of that subobject occurs? Will the pointer be valid?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the standard says here. From a practical point of view, I would say that it should be ok to store (!) it, since `(Base1*)this` should give you the same address before and after. But don't take my word on that ;)

Comment: What's `AnotherClass`? Is that supposed to be `Base1`?

Comment: Base1 and AnotherClass are different classes.

Comment: If it were the same I'd just call it Base1.

Comment: So does `Base1` inherit `AnotherClass`?

Comment: AnotherClass constructor takes Base1 pointer to stored it. I've edited the code. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: But now it depends on exactly what the `AnotherClass` constructor does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat dangerous pattern in general. It's possible to keep things strictly valid, but in the example shown, it's actually the conversion from `Base1*` to `AnotherClass*` which is not allowed by the Standard.

[[class.cdtor]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.cdtor#2) gives some restrictions on converting a pointer from derived class to base class:

> To explicitly or implicitly convert a pointer (a glvalue) referring to an object of class `X` to a pointer (reference) to a direct or indirect base class `B` of `X`, the construction of `X` and the construction of all of its direct or indirect bases that directly or indirectly derive from `B` shall have started and the destruction of these classes shall not have completed, otherwise the conversion results in undefined behavior.

When the initializer "`this`" for the `Base0` subobject is evaluated, the construction of `Derived` has started, but the construction of its `Base1` subobject has not started. But since there are no other classes in the inheritance tree which derive from `Base1`, the `Derived*` to `Base1*` conversion is okay. Converting `this` to a pointer to grandparent class would not be okay if the parent class constructor hasn't started; if the grandparent class is a virtual base class, the conversion isn't allowed until the last intermediate class which inherits it has started construction!

At first, that converted pointer points at an object whose (non-trivial) construction has not yet started, so it's subject to the restrictions in [[class.cdtor]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.cdtor#1) and [[basic.life]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#6). Mostly, you can't get at any of its base class subobjects or members yet. Copying that pointer, without any further implicit base class pointer conversions, is almost all you can legally do with it. So the example's implicit conversion from `Base1*` to `AnotherClass*` results in undefined behavior. It would be okay, though, if the `anotherObj` member had exactly the same type `Base1*`.